# Symfony3: Passing variables to FrameworkBundle:Template:template

Tags: php, routes, yaml, symfony

Just want to double check with the community, there are no chance to pass variables to a template rendered through FrameworkBundle:Template:template in the routing file right?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean a Twig template? Also which FrameworkBundle are you referring to? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @AlvinBunk if you give a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/render_without_controller.html you understand what I am talking about, best.

Comment: I see. I'm wondering if you still need variables this in this particular case? and thus the reason for your question... If that is so, then you could use global variables [described in this article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html). Just trying to help you out, since you may be looking for other solutions.

Comment: Well I was wondering because the only parameters i need to pass to the template would be the locale and the store, which are being elaborated in a base controller which is extended by my page "specific" one resulting in my page "specific" controller not doing anything other than rendering the template. I hope I gave you an idea of my perplexity. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design:

> But if you're rendering a simple template that doesn't need any data passed into it, you can avoid creating the controller entirely, by using the built-in `FrameworkBundle:Template:template` controller.
>   https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/render_without_controller.html

You can see that you can only pass three cache headers options and template name to render:

```
public function templateAction($template, $maxAge = null, $sharedAge = null, $private = null)
{
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/TemplateController.php#L37

So the anwser is: There is no chance to pass custom variables (excluding http cache headers options) to a template rendered through `FrameworkBundle:Template:template`.

Comment: thank you. Sometime it is good to double check and a feedback from another perspective. Cheers.